# Azure dynamic packaging / cdn

Tags: azure

I have a streaming endpoint in my media services enabled with CDN.
After encoding an mp4 with dynamic packaging and publishing it the publish url  is based off the hostname mentioned in the streaming endpoint. Isn't there going to be a different CDN hostname generated publish url?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Streaming hostname: Your streaming endpoint hostname remains the same after enabling CDN. You don’t need to make any changes to your media services workflow after CDN is enabled. For example, if your streaming endpoint hostname is strasbourg.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net, after enabling CDN, the exact same hostname is used."

More info here:
    http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/03/17/announcing-azure-media-services-integration-with-azure-cdn-content-delivery-network/